# What does Windows 7's Backup and Restore NOT backup?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, restore

So my old computer has a Linux partition which I want to remove to create some more space. I also have another partition with Windows 7, which has some important files and photos which I don't want to lose. The Linux partition is the primary partition so I can't just remove it and extend my Windows partition. I now want to use GParted to remove the Linux partition and move the Windows 7 partition to the left of the drive, but I've been told this process isn't consistent and can give errors.
My idea was to back up all my data on the Windows 7 partition (which is about 200gb) to my home server (which can store 5tb). I wanted to use Windows' built-in "Backup and Restore" function since it looks to be the easiest to use.

My question now is:
*Are there any things that Windows 7's backup and restore function doesn't backup?* Do programs stay installed? Do user accounts stay intact?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Windows 7 backup and restore with create a byte-copy image of any partitions you "check the box" for.  It *might* leave out the pagefile.. but I am not even sure about that.  Yes.. EVERYTHING will stay intact as long as it was part of what you imaged.  Where you are going to possibly have a problem..is how are you going to restore the image from a remote network drive?  You might want to put the image on a USB drive.. you will have a much easier time when you get to the restore part.

Comment: True, but because I don't know how big the image file is going to be, I upload it to the network drive to be absolutely sure I won't run out of disk space. I have another PC that I can use to retrieve the image file. But thank you so much for your answer!!